# How to retrieve only desired no.of rows from join result in sql

Tags: sql, join, select

Table team containing two columns:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | C |
| 4 | D |

Output: two columns (both names) :
|||
|:-:|:-:|
| A | B |
| A | C |
| B | C |
| B | D |
| C | D |
| C | A |

I think we can get this kind of output from

```
select * 
from team t1 
join team t2 on t1.id <> t2.id;
```

but it returns 3 rows for each name. I need only two rows for each name combined with any other name apart from its own (apart from A - A , B - B, C - C, D - D)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   select t1.id, t2.id from team t1 
  Cross   join team t2 on t1.id <> t2.id;
```

Comment: I have tried cross join already but again its same problem. I need only two rows for each id/name where as non-equi joins results in 3 rows